# How to get multiple images from folders in Xampp Server to display in angular page?

Tags: php, angular

I am trying to get multiple images from folders to display them into Angular using Php for backend.

I am honestly just confused not knowing where to start with this any help or just a lead would be really appreciated?

I've tried searching for an example but most I found were either uploading images (which I already achieved) or downloading 1 image.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your service which call PHP Api that returns images from images folder

```
getImages(): Observable<File> {
    let result: Observable<any> = this.http
      .get(`${this.baseUrl}/images`, { responseType: "blob" });
    return result;
}
```

create below method in your angular component for retrive images from api

```
getCustomerImages() {
    this.myService.getImages().subscribe(
      data => {
        //data returns all images you can store in images array
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
         console.log(error);

      });
  }
```